# How best to inject async client/request configuration into NSwag client code

Tags: c#, nswag

We are using NSwag generated client code for a web API. The API requires an Authorization header to be set on all requests.

This header value needs to be generated from async library methods (`ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync()` in case it matters).

So far the best option we've come up with is to create a class that implements

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
  HttpRequestMessage request,
  HttpCompletionOption completionOption,
  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

wrapping an `HTTPClient`, which would allow us to get the token and set the header before calling `SendAsync` on the wrapped `HttpClient`. We can then inject that class as the HttpClient used by the NSwag code.

I don't think we can use NSwag's `CreateHttpClientAsync` because I can't see how to inject the `ITokenAcquisition` (and other dependencies) into the base class. (Unless the client generation code is cleverer than I'm giving it credit for)

Have we missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution we came up with doesn't actually use any NSwag customisation in the end.

Instead we added a class inheriting from `DelegatingHandler` and overrode `SendAsync` there.

We then added our DelegatingHandler to the `HttpClient` passed to the NSwag client. e.g. during service registration:

```
    services.AddHttpClient<NSwagClientInterface, NSwagClientImplementation>((provider, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["BaseAddress"]);
        })
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyDelegatingHandler>();
```